# Wrong simple div layout in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, layout, html

Why won't IE9 position the `Orange` div next to the `Blue` one? The divs render just fine in other more civilized browsers, like Chrome or Firefox. The width values match perfectly, including the margins, but it takes extra 4 pixels to be removed from the e.g. `Gray` div in order to make the `Orange` one appear next to the `Blue` in IE9 (which leaves 4 pixels gap to the right of the `Orange` one, of course).

```
<div style="margin-top: 100px; background-color: GreenYellow; width: 740px; height: 100px; padding: 0px; overflow: visible;">
  <div style="background-color: CadetBlue; width: 210px; height: 100px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; float: left; overflow: visible;">
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: Black; width: 100px; height: 100px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 4px; padding: 0px; float: left; overflow: visible;">
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: FireBrick; width: 318px; height: 100px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 4px; padding: 0px; float: left; overflow: visible;">
    <div style="background-color: LightSalmon; width: 318px; height: 48px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; overflow: visible;">

      <!-- Gray -->
      <div style="width: 214px; height: 48px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; padding: 0px; float: left; background-color: #333333; overflow: visible;">
      </div>

      <!-- Blue -->
      <div style="width: 48px; height: 48px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 4px; padding: 0px; float: left; background-color: #00A8EC; overflow: visible;">
      </div>

      <!-- Orange -->
      <div style="width: 48px; height: 48px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 4px; padding: 0px; float: left; background-color: Orange; overflow: visible;">
      </div>

    </div>
    <div style="background-color: Gainsboro; width: 318px; height: 48px; margin: 4px 0px 0px 0px; padding: 0px; overflow: visible;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: Purple; width: 100px; height: 100px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 4px; padding: 0px; float: left; overflow: visible;">
  </div>
</div>
```

So how do I fix this? It's killing me ...

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LE6cy/

#### Update

Ok, I had no idea that this would affect it, but there is one more thing that I have on the page before these divs. It's a plain table. It seems that once the table is there, the error appears. So here is the whole HTML page (for real):

```
<table id="signature" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0" style="width: 750px; height: 100px; border: 0px;">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" style="height: 100px; width: 210px; background-color: #336666;">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div style="margin-top: 100px; background-color: GreenYellow; width: 740px; height: 100px; padding: 0px; overflow: visible;">
  <div style="background-color: CadetBlue; width: 210px; height: 100px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; float: left; overflow: visible;">
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: Black; width: 100px; height: 100px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 4px; padding: 0px; float: left; overflow: visible;">
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: FireBrick; width: 318px; height: 100px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 4px; padding: 0px; float: left; overflow: visible;">
    <div style="background-color: LightSalmon; width: 318px; height: 48px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; overflow: visible;">

      <!-- Gray -->
      <div style="width: 214px; height: 48px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; padding: 0px; float: left; background-color: #333333; overflow: visible;">
      </div>

      <!-- Blue -->
      <div style="width: 48px; height: 48px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 4px; padding: 0px; float: left; background-color: #00A8EC; overflow: visible;">
      </div>

      <!-- Orange -->
      <div style="width: 48px; height: 48px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 4px; padding: 0px; float: left; background-color: Orange; overflow: visible;">
      </div>

    </div>
    <div style="background-color: Gainsboro; width: 318px; height: 48px; margin: 4px 0px 0px 0px; padding: 0px; overflow: visible;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: Purple; width: 100px; height: 100px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 4px; padding: 0px; float: left; overflow: visible;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we get a JSFiddle/CodePen so we can see it in action please?

Comment: Do you have doctype set in your markup? I've made a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LE6cy/ and I see similar rendering by IE9 and Firefox. Jsfiddle has <!doctype html> set in the result iframe.

Comment: Can't reproduce what you describe. Saved your HTML to a file (no doctype, just your code) and it looks similar in IE7+, Firefox and Chrome. Congrats on that ;)

Comment: I updated the question. There is a table before the divs that I didn't mention because I wanted to simplify the question. I had no idea that it might affect the divs, sorry for that.

Comment: It still looks the similar in all the browsers. http://jsfiddle.net/LE6cy/1/ When you look at the fiddle do you see the issue? If not something else is going on. You need to recreate the issue in http://jsfiddle.net so that you can see it too.

Comment: I understand and yes, there is no error in fiddle on my end as well. But, when I save the content as HTML and open it, the error is there in IE 9.

Comment: The jsFiddle Works fine for me in IE... Doctype?

Comment: YES! It was doctype. @MatveyAndreyev, you mentioned this first, so please post it as an answer and I'll mark it correct. Thanks all!

Comment: Ok, posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have doctype set in your markup? I've made a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LE6cy and I see similar rendering by IE9 and Firefox. Jsfiddle has `<!doctype html>` set by default in the result iframe.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the empty text nodes as the `<div>`s are floated left